# How to set initial state for ngrx store application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am new to ngrx and am trying to manage my state with it.In my application, every agent(staff) have a group of customers that are tied to him/her. I am trying to set the initial state of each agent objects and i don't know how.

```
import { createReducer } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Cursor } from "../../../models/cursor";
import { Customer } from "../../../models/customer";

export interface State {
  agent_customer: {
    [agentId: number]: {
      customer: Customer[];
      cursors: Cursor;
      total: number;
      loading: boolean;
      errorMessage: string;
      items_per_page: number;
      pageSizeOptions: number[];
      pageIndex: number;
      searchKey: string;
    };
  };
}
```

Each agent object should have some initial state.

something like this

```
export const initialState: State = {
  agent_customer: {
    1: {
      customer: [],
      cursors: {
        after: "",
        before: "",
        hasNext: false,
        hasPrevious: false,
      },
      total: 0,
      loading: false,
      errorMessage: null,
      items_per_page: 2,
      pageSizeOptions: [2, 3, 5, 10, 15],
      pageIndex: 0,
      searchKey: "",
    },
  },
};
```

**Edit: This is an example of what should be in the store if all goes well.**

```
agent_customer: {
    198282: {
      customer: [],
      cursors: {
        after: "",
        before: "",
        hasNext: false,
        hasPrevious: false,
      },
      total: 0,
      loading: false,
      errorMessage: null,
      items_per_page: 2,
      pageSizeOptions: [2, 3, 5, 10, 15],
      pageIndex: 0,
      searchKey: "",
    },
    165436: {
      customer: [],
      cursors: {
        after: "",
        before: "",
        hasNext: false,
        hasPrevious: false,
      },
      total: 0,
      loading: false,
      errorMessage: null,
      items_per_page: 2,
      pageSizeOptions: [2, 3, 5, 10, 15],
      pageIndex: 0,
      searchKey: "",
    },
    981342: {
      customer: [],
      cursors: {
        after: "",
        before: "",
        hasNext: false,
        hasPrevious: false,
      },
      total: 0,
      loading: false,
      errorMessage: null,
      items_per_page: 2,
      pageSizeOptions: [2, 3, 5, 10, 15],
      pageIndex: 0,
      searchKey: "",
    },
  },
```

What i want is to be able to set the initial state of each subsequent object i add to the store.

Comment: This looks pretty good so far.. now just setup your reducer and pass in the initialState?

Comment: I wouldn't put the agents in the initialState, but rather have it minimal like this: `{ agent_customer: {}}`. Then I'd have an action called something like `"AGENTS INITIALISED"` and have a reducer that listens to it and populates the state with agents. This is how it's usually done.

Comment: But if you really want to go this route, you can use `.reduce()` on an array to create an object that follows this structure.

Comment: @ShamPooSham I initially thought of that also but i was afraid my `effect` for getting `Agent_customer` array might start before the `action` get processed in the reducer.Am i right or wrong?.

Comment: @walexy If you get the array through an effect, you need two actions: For example `"AGENTS REQUESTED"` and `"AGENTS LOADED"`. The first one is emitted as soon as you need to fetch the agents (I suppose in ngOnInit of app.component.ts) and has no payload, the second one returned by the effect when it's done loading the agents and contains the agents in the payload.

Comment: @walexy `"AGENTS REQUESTED"` wouldn't have a reduced associated with it, it's just there to make the effect trigger.

Comment: @ShamPooSham Take for example i have 3 `actions` name `GetAgentCustomerStart`, `GetAgentCustomerSuccess` and `GetAgentCustomerFailed`. When i trigger the `GetAgentCustomerStart` in the `ngOninit`, i will want to initailise the `AgentCustomerObject` in the `reducer`  and also trigger the `http-request` in the `effects`. My problem is if the `effects` get triggered before the reducer, the `http-request` wont have the necessary parameters to get the result i need because some of the parameters i need is in the state.

Comment: Why do you want to initialise the `AgentCustomerObject` after triggering `GetAgentCustomerStart`?

Comment: @ShamPooSham Because i want to set the `items_per_page`, `page_size_options` and `cursor_property` of that `agent` which will be used by the `effect`

Comment: How about you send it in the payload of the first action then?

Comment: I don't think `GetAgentCustomerStart` should trigger any change to the state, it should just trigger the effect. The effect will then, on success, trigger a change to the state that includes those things. I'm a bit unsure about `page_size_options` though, is it the same for all agents? Does it really need to be part of the state?

Comment: @ShamPooSham actually the initial `state` for `pageSizeOptions`, `items_per_page` ... is the same for all `agent`.Then after `GetAgentCustomerSuccess` action get dispatched  and  the  `adminstrator`  view an `agent customer page` i want to store all the customers for that particular `agent`  in the `store` so that if the `admin` is on second page of the `agent_customer page` and leaves that page i will be able to set the `mat-paginator` attribute etc so as to display the correct `pageNumber`, `pageIndex` and `item_per_page`  incase the admin visits that customers for that agent again

Comment: @ShamPooSham if i send the `items_per_page`, `pageSizeOptions` etc in the `payload` and the **admin** views the **third page** and change the `pageSizeOptions`, when the component get destroyed i wont have access to **mat-paginator** attributes any longer if i want to visit that page again thereby displaying the wrong `pageSizeOptions`, `pageIndex` and `items_per_page`

Comment: @ShamPooSham The reason why `pageSizeOptions`, `items_per_page` is in the `store` is because the `GetAgentCustomerSuccess` action result  is **paginated** and  i don't get all the `result at once.So if the `admin` view the **second page** or change the `pageSizeOption`, i have to store the `pageSizeOption`, and the `pageIndex` in the `store` so as to display the **correct page**, `pageSize` and `pageIndex` if the `admin` visit the **customers** for that particular `agent` again.

Comment: @walexy I'm not sure I get you right, but if you send it in the payload you can let the effect store the `items_per_page`, `pageSizeOptions` etc when it's done loading. I mean... should you really show the grid before the data is loaded anyways?

Comment: And `pageSizeOptions` can't change, right? It looks like a static array of possible values, that's why I say I don't think it belongs to the state.

Comment: @ShamPooSham You are right. `PageSizeOptions` don't change at all. i just decided to put it in the store anyway.But other values change like Items_per_page, pageIndex, cursors etc

Comment: @ShamPooSham you said **"but if you send it in the payload you can let the effect store the `items_per_page`, `pageSizeOptions` etc when it's done loading"**.You are right.That is going to work but the problem comes when am in the third page for example and i leave the `agent_customer page`, i lose all my current state for that page **(pageIndex, items_per_page)** when the component get destroyed.

Comment: @walexy I'm really confused. The effect should trigger an action that causes the store state to update. Do you destroy the store state when leaving the page?

Comment: @ShamPooSham i was replying to what you said about not storing the `pageIndex`, `items_per_page` in the store that i should just pass it as payload to the action. I didn't say the store state will get destroyed.

Comment: @wasely yes, but after I said that the effect should store `pageIndex` and `item_per_page` when it's done loading, together with the result it got. So it will be in the store.

Comment: @ShamPooSham Thanks alot. You have really been helpfull. I will try to do that

Comment: @walexy no problem :) you can start a chat with me if you have further questions

Comment: @ShamPooSham How do i chat u up??

Comment: @walexy [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238232/walexy-and-poosham), I created a chat room

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Store Module for this-

`import {createAction, props} from '@ngrx/store'`

Refer to the official guide-
https://ngrx.io/guide/store
https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers

Please check out this gist -
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/662

Comment: I know how to use use `createAction` and `props`.what i want to do is to set the initial state of the store object. Have edited the question so check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the type, then set the initialState of your reducer

```
import { Action, createFeatureSelector, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ACTION } from './actions';
import { Entity} from './entity';

export interface CustomState {
   agent: Entity[] // Pass the entity type, on this case Entity[]
}

// type the initial state with your interface(state)
const initialState: CustomState = {
    agent: [
     // Pass here each object of type (Entity)
     {
       total: 0,
       loading: false,
       errorMessage: null,
       items_per_page: 2,
       ...
     }
]
}

const reducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(ACTION, (state, { payload }) => ({ ...state, agent: payload }))
);

export function customReducer(state: CustomState, action: Action) {
    return reducer(state, action)
};

export const getCustomState = createFeatureSelector<CustomState>('customName');
```

Comment: Each `agent` might have different `state`. Take for example i load data for `agent-10909` and add it to the store , i might decide to change the `pageSizeOption` and `item_per_page` in th UI for that specific `agent` state.